# Android Multiple Permissions Error

Tags: java, android

I have a method that should check if some permission that I need to have are Granted or not :

```
public boolean checkCamera(){
    String[] permissions= new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

    int result;
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String p:permissions) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),p);
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS );
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If not, it request these permissions. The problem is, if I denied one of them it pass as valid Permission.

```
private void requestPermissionCamera(){
    if(checkCamera()){
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
        imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent,requestCodeCamera);
    }
}
```

In the moment that checks, it's not returning false as it should and on RequestResult the same thing.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent,requestCodeCamera);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not All permissions are granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        case READ_STORAGE:
```

Comment: You can't use conditional statement with switch. If is incompatible with switch

Comment: Either start with switch and case and break. Or if conditions

Comment: @Nathiel Barros did you find the solution??

Comment: Yeah, but not with this, I'm using a Lib to perform ! [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)